# Powershell - Invalid attempt to call FieldCount - Reader Closed?

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I have a PowerShell script that I use to loop over a list of SQL Servers and pull extended event data from those servers. It works great on 95% of my SQL Servers but about 5% of my SQL Servers I get this error:

> Write-DataTable:System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException:
>   Exception calling "WriteToServer" with "1" argument(s):
>
> "Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed."
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Invalid attempt to call FieldCount
>   when reader is closed.
>
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_FieldCount() at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(IDataReader reader) at
>   CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Object )
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
>   funcContext, Exception exception) at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame) at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame) at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame).Message

I don't understand why my script works on most SQL Servers but not all.

My PowerShell script:

```
#Create your SQL connection string to your central collection database  
$ServerAConnectionString = "Data Source=SourceServer;Initial Catalog=SourceDatabase;Integrated Security=True;" $ServerAConnection = new-object system.data.SqlClient.SqlConnection($ServerAConnectionString);

#Create a Dataset to hold the DataTable from DBServers 
$dataSet = new-object "System.Data.DataSet" "DBServers" $query = "SET NOCOUNT ON;" $query = $query + " SELECT ServerName, FilePath " $query = $query
        + " FROM dbo.SourceTable " $query = $query + " WHERE Domain = 'domain'  " $query = $query + " AND XEventQueryEnabled = 1 "
        #write-host $query;

#Create a DataAdapter which youll use to populate the DataSet with the instances to collect from 
$dataAdapter = new-object "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter" ($query, $ServerAConnection) $dataAdapter.Fill($dataSet) #| Out-Null   $ServerAConnection.Open() $sourceConnection  = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection($SourceConnectionString)


$CollectionTime = date;    foreach($a in $dataSet.Tables[0].Rows) {   write-host "DBServer: " $a.ServerName;       # set connection string for the remote server
    $SourceConnectionString = "Server="+$a.Servername+"; Initial Catalog = master; integrated security = true"    # set connection string for the central collection server
    $DestinationConnectionString = "Data Source=RepositoryServer;Initial Catalog=RepositoryDatabase;Integrated Security=True"
     try
    {
    $sql =  "        WITH cte (event_data) as "
    $sql =  $sql + " (SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) AS event_data "
    $sql =  $sql + " FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'"+$a.FilePath+"MyXevents*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)) "
    $sql =  $sql + " SELECT @@SERVERNAME, * FROM cte "
    $sql =  $sql + " WHERE  SWITCHOFFSET(event_data.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetimeoffset'),DATEPART(Tzoffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())) > '2/1/16' "
       try{
            write-host "Collecting XEvent XML Data from Remote SQL Server.";
            $tableName = "RepositoryTable"
            $sourceConnection.ConnectionString = $SourceConnectionString
            $sourceConnection.open()
            $commandSourceData  = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$sourceConnection)

            $reader = $commandSourceData.ExecuteReader()

            $commandSourceData.CommandTimeout = '300'
        }
        Catch
        {
            $ex1 = $_.Exception.Message

        }  # end CATCH block for bad file/offset
            write-host "Inserting XEvent XML Data to Repository.";
            $bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $DestinationConnectionString
            $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $tableName
            $bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000
            $bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0
            $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($reader)

        $reader.Close()    }
    catch
    {
        $ex = $_.Exception
        Write-Host "Write-DataTable$($connectionName):$ex.Message"
    }
    finally
    {
        write-host "Finished Collecting XEvent XML Data.";
       # $reader.close()
    }
    $sourceConnection.close() }
#Close the connection as soon as you are done with it $ServerAConnection.Close()
```

Comment: that would happen if an exception is thrown from the inner try block. why not just remove the inner try block? how are you expecting the code to still be able to continue if it wasn't able to construct $reader?

Comment: I removed the inner try block and found that the true problem was a sqlcommand timeout.  My error was placing the sqlcommand timeout after the executereader() command.  After I placed the timeout property before the executereader() everything works fine now.  Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the SQL Command Timeout property was specified after the Execute Reader.

Before:

```
foreach($a in $dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
  write-host "DBServer: " $a.ServerName;   
   # set connection string for the remote server
    $SourceConnectionString = "Server="+$a.Servername+"; Initial Catalog = master; integrated security = true"
   # set connection string for the central collection server
    $DestinationConnectionString = "Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True"

     try
    {
    $sql =  "        WITH cte (event_data) as "
    $sql =  $sql + " (SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) AS event_data "
    $sql =  $sql + " FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'"+$a.FilePath+"*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)) "
    $sql =  $sql + " SELECT @@SERVERNAME, * FROM cte "
    $sql =  $sql + " WHERE  SWITCHOFFSET(event_data.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetimeoffset'),DATEPART(Tzoffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())) between '2/1/16' and '2/2/16' "

       try{
            write-host "Collecting XEvent XML Data from Remote SQL Server.";
            $tableName = "XEventXMLData"
            $sourceConnection.ConnectionString = $SourceConnectionString
            $sourceConnection.open()
            $commandSourceData  = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql,$sourceConnection)

            $reader = $commandSourceData.ExecuteReader()

            $commandSourceData.CommandTimeout = '300'

        }
        Catch
        {
            $ex1 = $_.Exception.Message

        }  # end CATCH block for bad file/offset
            write-host "Inserting XEvent XML Data to Repository.";
            $bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $DestinationConnectionString
            $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $tableName
            $bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000
            $bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0
            $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($reader)

        $reader.Close()
   }
    catch
    {
        $ex = $_.Exception
        Write-Host "Write-DataTable$($connectionName):$ex.Message"
    }
    finally
    {
        write-host "Finished Collecting XEvent XML Data.";
       # $reader.close()
    }
    $sourceConnection.close()

}
```

After:

```
foreach($a in $dataSet.Tables[0].Rows)
{
  write-host "DBServer: " $a.ServerName;   
   # set connection string for the remote server
    $SourceConnectionString = "Server="+$a.Servername+"; Initial Catalog = master; integrated security = true"
   # set connection string for the central collection server
    $DestinationConnectionString = "Data Source=;Initial Catalog=;Integrated Security=True"

     try
    {
    $sql =  "        WITH cte (event_data) as "
    $sql =  $sql + " (SELECT CAST(event_data AS XML) AS event_data "
    $sql =  $sql + " FROM sys.fn_xe_file_target_read_file(N'"+$a.FilePath+"*.xel', NULL, NULL, NULL)) "
    $sql =  $sql + " SELECT @@SERVERNAME, * FROM cte "
    $sql =  $sql + " WHERE  SWITCHOFFSET(event_data.value('(event/@timestamp)[1]', 'datetimeoffset'),DATEPART(Tzoffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET())) > '2/1/16' "

    write-host "Collecting XEvent XML Data from Remote SQL Server.";
    $sourceConnection.ConnectionString = $SourceConnectionString
    $sourceConnection.open()

    $commandSourceData = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
    $commandSourceData.CommandText = $sql
    $commandSourceData.Connection = $sourceConnection
    $commandSourceData.CommandTimeout = 0

    $reader = $commandSourceData.ExecuteReader()

    write-host "Inserting XEvent XML Data to Repository.";
    $bulkCopy = new-object ("Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy") $DestinationConnectionString
    $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $tableName
    $bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000
    $bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 0
    $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($reader)

    $reader.Close()
   }
    catch
    {
        $ex = $_.Exception
        Write-Host "Write-DataTable$($connectionName):$ex.Message"
    }
    finally
    {
        write-host "Finished Collecting XEvent XML Data.";
       # $reader.close()
    }
    $sourceConnection.close()

}
```